# How to set a PHP variable?

Tags: php, variables

I need to set the variable below on page load:

```
 if($_GET['country'] == 'uk'){
 }
```

I thought

```
 $country=uk;
```

would work, but obviously not?

Orginal code checks the URL as: `index.php?country=uk`

I want to perfom the same, but within the page &

not have the variable string at the end of the suffix

Comment: `$country='uk';`  Since `uk` is a string, needs to be inside quotes. `$test=1;` would be fine in your format since thats a number

Comment: what is your question? not clear at all whatyou want to do?

Comment: [Getting started](http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php)

Comment: What do you mean by 'within the same page' ? and what is the 'suffix' you're talking about ?

Comment: "index.php?country=uk" works - "index.php" - does not

Comment: So what about `$_GET['country'] = 'uk';`...?!

Comment: deceze - I already tried that, doens't work either. I'm beginning to think there are other factors involved.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to acheive?

```
 <?php
    if((!isset($_GET['country']) or ($_GET['country']!='uk')))
        header('Location:index.php?country=uk');
    //your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings need to be between simple or double quotes. There's a slight difference between the two of them but you should not worry about this at this point. So you need to have :

```
$country = 'uk';
```

or :

```
$country = "uk";
```

I would also recommend in your test to use the '===' operand, instead of '==', because it will not only test the value but also the type of your variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, unfortunately that isn't doing what I need it to. I've edited my original post to give more information, basically I need to emulate:

index.php?country=uk

Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

When you have strings in php to store in variables

you need to use quotes like so:

```
 <?php  $country = "uk"; 
 ?>
```